# Configuración Apache Tomcat 9

Tags: java, eclipse, apache, tomcat, sencha

Tengo un proyecto Java en Eclipse. El front-end está implementado con Sencha Extjs (Javascript). Compilo el proyecto con JDK 1.8. Y hasta ahora utilizaba Apache Tomcat 7. Con está configuración todo me iba bien, al imprimir un grid me salia así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora he tenido que pasarme a Apache Tomcat 9. Y aquí ha surgido el problema. Al intentar imprimir nuevamente el grid, me aparece de esta forma (sin formato?):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tenéis idea de que puede ser? El codigo es exactamente el mismo, simplemente desplegado en un Tomcat o en otro.

Cualquier ayuda se agradece :)

Comment: ni idea, pero tomcat sólo va a servir los recursos e implementar servlets si es el caso. ve a [edit] la pregunta, añade el código que genera esta página y revisa qué sale en consla del navegador

Comment: Lectura sugerida: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 Saludos.

Comment: yo encontré este video sobre tomcat, quizás te puede ayudar en algo.
https://youtu.be/j1CZ2fvX0Rc

Answer (score 0):

Gracias por la respuesta.
Indagando más, vi que en Tomcat 9 no me cogía correctamente el fichero css referenciado con:

```html
'<link href="' + this.stylesheetPath + '" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />'
```

Lo que he hecho es poner el codigo css dentro la etiqueta  y ahora sí me ha funcionado.

Gracias Alfabravo por tu tiempo!